# Is it possible to use attributes of the final estimator of a pipeline object in scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have created a pipeline object which uses countvectorizer and MultinomialNB. MultinomialNB instances have an attributes named intercept_. If I try to access this attribute using the Pipeline object I am getting the error that 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'intercept_'. I am wondering if there is a way to access attributes of the final estimator class in a Pipeline instance. I would like to thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using either the `steps` or `named_steps` attributes, see this question: [Getting model attributes from scikit-learn pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822756/getting-model-attributes-from-scikit-learn-pipeline)