# Access attributes with sklearn Pipeline and MultiOutputRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, attributes, pipeline

Suppose a machine learning model, such as LightGBM's `LGBMRegressor`, has an attribute `best_iteration_`. How is this attribute accessible after calling the `fit` method, whereby sklearn's `Pipeline` and `MultiOutputRegressor` were utilized?

For `Pipeline` I've tried `named_steps`:

```
foo.named_steps['reg']
```

which returns the following object `sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.`

Then, I've tried `.estimators_`:

```
foo.named_steps['reg'].estimators_
```

which returns a list. However, the list contains the initial parameters that were supplied to the model.

Could someone please explain the ideal way to access a model's attributes?

Comment: This might be part of the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822756/getting-model-attributes-from-scikit-learn-pipeline/58359509#58359509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `foo` is a sklearn pipeline object, if so, you can probably do this:

```
for e in foo.named_steps['reg'].estimators_:
    print(e.best_iteration_)
```

- `foo.named_steps['reg'].estimators_` returns a list of estimators
  inside of MultiOutputRegressor.
- `e` is the LGBMRegressor you used
  inside of your MultiOutputRegressor.

You can replace `best_iteration_` with any attributes of the model you wanted to access.

Comment: Yes, `foo` has type `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`. However, I tried your `for` loop suggestion, and `None` is returned.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html#lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.best_iteration_), and I quote:
`The best iteration of fitted model if early_stopping_rounds has been specified.`
You need to specify `early_stopping_rounds` or it will return None.